# Adorners overlap controls that are above the adorned element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, adorner, adornerlayer

Hey, I'm having an issue with adorners. I created resize adorners which have four Thumb controls, one for each of the corners of the control being decorated. The control is being drawn on a Canvas, and the user may select it and resize it.
The canvas is hosted on a ZoomBoxPanel control, which basically applies a ScaleTransform and TranslateTransform to the whole thing to provide zoom and pan support.

Problem is that when an item is outside the bounds of the zoom panel, and the item is cropped as you'd expect (like when you set ClipToBounds = true), you can still see the adorners! Could anyone please tell me a way to prevent this?

[Evidence. The black square is the one selected, two resize thumbs are visible (right), the others should not be visible (left)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q2E9.jpg)

Thanks!!

Comment: Fixed it, solution was to put an AdornerElement object immediately above the Canvas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, solution was to put an AdornerDecorator object immediately above the Canvas :)

```
<AdornerDecorator>
   <Canvas>
</AdornerDecorator>
```